# Functional equation for $\zeta$ function Apostol explanation

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-explanation, analytic-number-theory

> We have, with $s= \sigma + it $,  $$\zeta(s,a) = \Gamma(1-s)I(s,a) $$
>   if $\sigma > 1$. edit: Here 
>   $$ I(s,a):= \frac{1}{2\pi i } \int_C \frac{z^{s-1}e^{az}}{1 -e^z} \,dz $$ 
>   where $C$ is the Hankel Integral. (pg253, Apostol, Introduction to Analytic Number Theory).

Here $\Gamma(1-s)$ is not defined when $s \in \mathbb{N}$. What does Apostol mean? He also wrote similar thing, on page 259,

> For **all** $s$ we have 
>   $$ \zeta(1-s) = 2 (2 \pi )^{-s} \Gamma(s) \cos \frac{\pi s }{2} \zeta(s) $$

But the Gamma function is not defined for $s \in \{ 0, -1, \ldots , \}$ and $\zeta$ is not defined for $s = 1$?

Comment: Presumably, $I(s,a)$ contains a factor of $\sin\pi s$ in the numerator?

Comment: @Antinous, I have edited, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that $$\zeta(-n)=\frac{B_{n+1}}{n+1},$$
where $B_{m}$ are the Bernoulli numbers, and $B_{2m+1}=0$ for all $m>0$. Also, $\cos(\pi s/2)=0$ for $s<0$ odd.

So, for example, combined we have
$$\lim_{s\to-1} \Gamma(s)\cos(\pi s/2)\zeta(s)=\frac{\pi}{24},$$
but taken individually, $\Gamma(-1)=+\infty$, $\zeta(-1)=-1/12$, $\cos(-\pi/2)=0$. In the limit the product of the $\Gamma$ and $\cos$ terms actually converge to a number !

Similarly for your first expression.

Comment: Sorry, so how does this explained that RHS is not defined at $s \in \{ 0, -1 ,\ldots, \}$ ? Even if we put $s= -n$, we have $\infty \cdot 0 $ on RHS(?)

Comment: See my updated answer.

Comment: Ok, this is how I understand it now: For first equation, let RHS = $f(s)$. $\zeta(s ) = f(s) $ on all points for which $s$ is defined on both sides and $\sigma>1$.  So we may analytically extend, at points where $f(s)$ is not defined, the limit of the LHS. i.e. $\lim_{ s \rightarrow 1} f(s) = \zeta(2)$. Is this right?

Comment: I think the point is that the standard definition of $\zeta(s,a)$ which is defined only for $\Re(s)>1$ and $\Re(a)>0$ is being analytically continued to the whole complex plane (perhaps except for a finite number of points, not sure off the top of my head, i.e. possibly meromorphic), by showing it to be equal to $\Gamma(1-s)I(s,a)$ for $\Re(s)>1$ and $\Re(a)>0$. But, since $\Gamma(1-s)I(s,a)$ converges for the whole complex plane (perhaps meromorphic, not sure) then we can analytically continue $\zeta(s,a)$. Should be that in the limit $\Gamma(1-s)I(s,a)$ is defined for negative integers.